# Raspberry Pi 3: booting gets stuck at "random: crng init done"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, boot

I downloaded the program I found on http://www.samplerbox.org/makeitsoftware and am trying to run it on a Raspberry Pi 3 from a USB SD card reader.  I have successfully programmed my Raspberry Pi to boot from USB and I can get it to recognize the program.  However, when booting it gets stuck at `random: crng init done`.  I have read in several places that I should press the enter key or move the mouse at this point, but the machine does not recognize I am doing anything.

Before anyone writes back, I want to let you all know that the Python language looks like gibberish to me.  That means that if anyone gives me directions they need to be absurdly simple.

Comment: did you try to search `random: crng init done` in Google ? Maybe it has nothing to do with this program. And maybe someone already had this problem and he resolved it. And maybe you can find solution on some Raspberry Forum.

Comment: I have tried many times and have followed the advice I have read such as setting initcall_debug=1 and boot_delay=5.  Like you said, the program is probably not the issue.

Comment: I checked some links in Google and as for me it is problem with system or SD card. I would start from beginning - I would format SD card and reinstall system.

Comment: did you check [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=209093)? setting `initcall_debug` is only meant to cause more detailed messages to be printed so you can figure out what's wrong. It isn't meant to actually do anything to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason you're booting from `SD -> USB -> PI` rather than `SD -> PI`? The docs for samplerbox suggests to run the normal way from an image on a micro SD. There may be things pre-configured in the image that require that.

Answer (score 2):

The partuuid no longer matches the SD card.
If you boot the sd card and mount the boot drive /dev/mmcblk0p1 (probably) Formatted FAT. You can edit the cmdline.txt file

By booting on another machine and running sudo blkid /dev/sd?(enter drive here) it will give you the PARTUUID
Then each partition is numbered -01 or -02

For example then you will replace the old PTUUID with the new one in the cmdline.txt

Example Using my system numbers.You will have to find yours

Replace old:
root=PARTUUID=13e42378-02

replace with New:
root=PARTUUID=6212a136-02

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what happened is that during a power failure, my raspberries just stopped turning on. Then I tried to restore from backup. After a copy of the backup to a USB flash drive and an attempt to boot, this message came out, which in my case meant that the partitioning of the disk did not match what it was before the system crashed. It turns out that it is necessary not only to format the flash drive before attempting to restore, but also to create partitions on it the same as on the broken system.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English language community. Please translate your answer.

Comment: I ran it through google translate, not sure the accuracy but it looks at least passable to me...

Comment: at least it translated

Comment: @Z4-tier [Please read the policy on non-english posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680) - you're not supposed to translate posts unless you're completely sure OP understands english. Based on your comment, it seems you don't know OP, and OP doesn't have enough on-site content to indicate they understand english, making your edit here inappropriate.

Comment: @Zoe Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't see it covered in the help center and felt this was a reasonable solution to a relatively minor issue. Clearly the author was able to read and understand the question (either directly or through a translator) well enough to write what appears to be a completely passable response. I had originally flagged it for moderators but retracted it because this seems very trivial. If you disagree, please raise a moderator flag or open a post on Meta. You could also roll back my edit, downvote and then vote to delete (which seems excessive, but it's up to you).

Comment: @Z4-tier what's done is done - I'm not gonna revert it and I'm not gonna mod-flag. It's one of those potentially counter-intuitive policies that don't always make sense to everyone, so I don't see a reason to hammer a mod into this. Also the fact that it isn't in the help center makes it harder to find - shit happens when information isn't easily available where you'd expect it to be. Just keep it in mind :)